# How to realize protocol Capability in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

See following Code:

```
public class Base<Capability> { }
public protocol Traceable {}
public protocol Routeable {}

extension Base: Traceable where Capability == Traceable {}
extension Base: Routeable where Capability == Routeable {}
```

In some way, the `Base` Class can provide Capability implementation `Traceable` & `Routeable` by decalaring a subclass like

```
public class Tracer: Base<Traceable> {}
public class Router: Base<Routeable> {}
```

**Here is the problem:**
How can I declare a subclass with Both `Traceable` & `Routeable`.

---

I've be considering decalaring the subclass like

```
public class Tracer: Base<Traceable & Routeable> {}
```

But it comes out that extension constraints can only be with operator : or == .

Any Solutions or other ways for `Capability` purpose?

Comment: Do you really need a Base class for the capabilities implementation? It would be easier to just use protocols and extensions for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `typealias` that conforms both.

```
typealias Capability = Traceable & Routeable
```

You can use [Protocol Extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html). Add default implementations for the properties or functions to make them optional (or mark them optional with `@objc` flag).

```
extension Traceable {
    // put default implementation
}

extension Routeable {
    // put default implementation
}
```

and use:

```
extension Base: Capability {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It works, but I wish all Capabilities can be optional.

Comment: I updated the answer to make the implementations optional.

Comment: The problem is that: 1 - For subclass, optional capability should not be available if not announced; 2 - the default implementation may access the Base class itself... If Swift can provide a `or` ability for extension constraints, this won't be a problem. Thank you anyway,